# Live Agent Custom Chat Page

Tags: liveagent

I'm implementing live agent and I experience an issue when I came to the stage to create a Custom Chat Page.

So I went to pages and create a new page using the code I got from the "code inspector" on the default window and another try with the sample code provided on the Live Agent Developers Guide.
I did both simply to get a preview of how it works.

When I preview it seems fine but when I add it on my sandbox Automated Invitation Button, a force.com page shows up saying Authorisation Required!

[image: The error message shown]

Of course, when I don't setup a Custom Chat Page, everything works perfectly fine.
Any idea where I got it wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Niko.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the context user has access to the page you have created, if this is in a site go to

Setup > Develop > Sites > Click on the Site Name > Edit Visualforce Pages and add the page.

If this is not a site just enable the page for the profile of the user trying to view the page.

Comment: Hello, I came along a new issue, hopefully your expertise will help me out once more!

Comment: @Niko: Do you mind creating a new question? Thanks.